# Changing shape in appWidget

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I'm trying to change the color in the shape of an appWidget. I have a rectangle with corners, my goal is to change the background(solid) color and the border colors.

My widget layout is a RelativeLayout with an ImageView for the background, the src attribute of this ImageView is this shape :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
  <corners
      android:radius="5dp"
      android:topRightRadius="5dp"
      android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
      android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp" />
  <stroke
      android:width="1dp"
      android:color="@android:color/white" />
  <solid android:color="@color/transparent"/>
</shape>
```

Here is what I'm trying to do when I try to change the background color :

```
RoundRectShape sd = new RoundRectShape(new float[]{30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30}, null, null);
bmp_bg = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 20, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp_bg);
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setColor(0xFF0000FF);
sd.draw(c, p);
remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageClock, bmp_bg);
```

But the background doesn't change. Is this a good way to do that ? Or am I completly wrong ? 
thx

EDIT : 
I tried this too without any effect :

```
CustomShapeClockWidget cscw = new CustomShapeClockWidget(0xFF0000FF, 0xFFFF0000);
bmp_bg = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 20, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp_bg);
cscw.draw(c);
remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageClock, bmp_bg);
```

with the class CustomShapeClockWidget being :

```
public class CustomShapeClockWidget extends ShapeDrawable {

    private int bgColor, strokeColor;
    private Paint fillPaint, strokePaint;

    public CustomShapeClockWidget(int bgColor, int strokeColor){
        this.bgColor = bgColor;
        this.strokeColor = strokeColor;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Shape shape, Canvas canvas, Paint paint){
        fillPaint = this.getPaint();
        strokePaint = new Paint(fillPaint);

        fillPaint.setColor(bgColor);

        strokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        strokePaint.setStrokeWidth(1.0f);
        strokePaint.setColor(strokeColor);

        shape.draw(canvas, fillPaint);
        shape.draw(canvas, strokePaint);
    }

}
```

Comment: (A very late comment but) Are you updating the appwidget after calling remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap?

Answer (score 0):

(Late answer, hope it helps anyone struggling with shapes in appwidgets like me)

The first code you wrote is almost complete, it just lacks the call to `resize(float, float)` necessary before `draw(Canvas, Paint)`. There is no need to create a custom shape object.

The [SDK documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/RoundRectShape.html#draw(android.graphics.Canvas,%20android.graphics.Paint)) says this for `RoundRectShape` and other shapes:

> Draw this shape into the provided Canvas, with the provided Paint.
>   **Before calling this, you must call resize(float, float)**.